# How to get an equivalent for MSSQL's STUFF function in microsoft access sql

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

For example; I have this number `20420450901590` and I want to write a query that will update it to the `204/2045090/1/59/0`.
The following `STUFF` function will do that on `MS SQL` but not on `ACCESS` DB.

```
DECLARE @Acct_No nvarchar(100),@Acct_No nvarchar(50)

set @Acct_No = '20420450901590 '

select STUFF (STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@Acct_No, 4, 0, '/'), 12,0, '/'), 14,0, '/'), 17,0, '/')
```

Method 2: If I use

```
SELECT LEFT(@Acct_No,3) + '/' + LEFT(@Acct_No,7) + RIGHT(@Acct_No,1)
```

doesn't give me the result I expect

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the format you want:

```
SELECT LEFT(Table1.Acct_No,3) + '/' + MID(Table1.Acct_No,4,7) + '/' 
       + MID(Table1.Acct_No,11,1) + '/' + MID(Table1.Acct_No,12,2) + '/' 
       + MID(Table1.Acct_No,14,1)
FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you in ***MS Access***:

```
LEFT(@Acct_No,3) & '/' & MID(@Acct_No,4,7) 
       & '/' & MID(@Acct_No,11,1) & '/' & MID(@Acct_No,12,2) 
       & '/' & MID(@Acct_No,14,1);
```

Comment: Thanks guys...I used this and it works fine    SELECT LEFT(@Acct_No,3) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Acct_No, 4, 7) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Acct_No, 11, 1) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Acct_No, 12, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Acct_No, 14, 1)